# Rename The Witcher 3 DLCs tags adding missing "the"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

We currently have [witcher-3-blood-and-wine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/witcher-3-blood-and-wine) and [witcher-3-hearts-of-stone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/witcher-3-hearts-of-stone) which are DLCs for [the-witcher-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3), so shouldn't they be renamed [the-witcher-3-blood-and-wine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3-blood-and-wine) and [the-witcher-3-hearts-of-stone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3-hearts-of-stone) to fit the actual game's name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have been renamed to [the-witcher-3-hearts-of-stone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3-hearts-of-stone) and [the-witcher-3-blood-and-wine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3-blood-and-wine).